# android fragment not filling whole screen

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a one activity app, that will use fragments navigating using a navigation component,

navigation works ok, but the fragment is not filling the screen...

[image: fragment not filling]

> activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:background="@color/black"
/>
```

> fragment_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorAccent"
tools:context=".MainFragment">

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/loginButton"
    android:layout_width="108dp"
    android:layout_height="108dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/loginicon" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/playButton"
    android:layout_width="106dp"
    android:layout_height="108dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/playicon" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="347dp"
    android:layout_height="151dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/robotface" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="Welcome to MyAI"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView" />
```

Why is my fragment not filling the parent?

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

Comment: Are you sure you inflated the `Fragment`'s layout correctly in its `onCreateView()` method? You need to pass the `ViewGroup` parameter as the parent argument in the `inflate()` call. Also, is there a reason that you're using a `ConstraintLayout` as the `Fragment` container, in `activity_main`? If nothing else is going to be placed into that along with the `Fragment`, you should instead use a `FrameLayout`, or the new `FragmentContainerView`.

Comment: @MikeM. Thanks a lot!, just by using "FrameLayout" all is fixed now. please create the answer to accept it as the solution, cheers!